# В каком виде файлы из которых состоит сайт должны загрузиться пользователю?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть есть много файлов js, css и других, многие из них, так или иначе подключены к index.html... И если я правильно понимаю процесс происходящего, то пользователь зайдя на сайт, грузит все файлы которые подключены к index.html. А как должно быть на самом деле? Принимаю во внимание влияние минимизаторов и склейщиков, какие файлы должны быть прописаны в index.html? Расскажите подробней, как это должно быть сделано?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос. Какие нужны для работы сайта, такие и отдавать юзеру.

Comment: Вопрос не "какие", а "как-в каком виде"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так все и должно быть. Не очень понимаю суть вопроса

В принципе можно и js и css запихнуть в html в соответствующие теги, но так почти никто не делает.

Браузер сначала грузит html, затем все подключенные css и js затем рендерит страницу, затем подгружает картинки. Порядок может меняться в зависиости от браузера.

Именно для того чтобы браузер не делал кучу запросов к серверу и грузил все быстро js обфусцируют, собирают в один файл. Та же история с css. JS часто загружают асинхронно, чтобы не блокировать рендлеринг страницы.

Мелкие картинки объединяют в одну (называется css sprite) тоже чтобы загружать одну картинку а не много.

Comment: Начсёт "не делают" - очень сомнительно. Делают, и так, и так. И даже эдак :) Всё зависит исключительно от конкретного случая. А может и всё сразу (прошитые в html css/js + подключение внешних файлов + менеджер скриптов/стилей, который читает внешние упаковывает их в один).

Comment: @shata "Так" никто например не сует css в тег style прямо в html. За редкими исключениями, например в email, где это необходимость, или в случаях когда скорость загрузки страницы уж очень сильно страдает от загрузки более одного файла. В основном же js и css подключают отдельными файлами, но количество этих файлов стараются свести к минимум, чаще всего к одному js и одному css

Comment: >никто например не сует css в тег style прямо в html

И внимательно смотрим на потроха, например, ibm.com, sourceforge.net, www.w3schools.com, google.com и ещё сотен тысяч сайтов :-)

Comment: @klopp это жесточайший хайлоад, хотя даже в жестком хайлоаде мало кто так делает. С другой стороны да, если это правильно собирать, вреда нет, сплошная польза

Comment: Ну, в качестве примера можно взять, например, какую-нибудь докувики или что-то вроде. С одной стороны, в HTML прошиваются базовые скрипты и стили, которые обеспечивают основной функционал, работу с неймспейсами, отображение тулбаров, кэширование спрайтов и т.д. С другой - есть менеджер плагинов, который занимается упаковкой и подключением юзерских стилей и скриптов, уже в единых внешних блоках. Так что все способы в одном флаконе тут вполне имеют право на жизнь.

Comment: @shatal обычно при разработке подключают кучу файлов отдельно, так удобнее ориентироваться в коде. При выкатывании проекта на продакшн все собирают и минифицируют в один файл. Например Grunt для этого есть или gulp

Comment: @klopp В общем да, тут нужно соблюдать некий баланс, то что нужно для базового рендеринга приложения можно сувать прямо в код, остальное в подключаемом файле, а редко используемые скрипты подключать динамически по мере необходимости

Comment: >При выкатывании проекта на продакшн все собирают и минифицируют в один файл. Например Grunt для этого есть или gulp

Вот по этому я и уточняю, так-как я настраиваю gulp. А что ещё странно, так это то, что у gulp-bower ( да и в самом Bower ) есть два режима development и production, в которых он подключает библиотеки в index.html... И вот эта опция, подразумевает, что библиотеки будут подключены, как отдельные файлы, а не как слитый в один..

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос не "какие", а "как-в каком виде"..

В своих форматах (Css в css, js в js, JPG в JPG и т.п.).
Можно конечно "сжимать", если текстовые форматы - убирать пробелы и переносы на новую строку.
В графике сжимать до оптимального вида, без явной потери в визуализации (качество, разрешение).
И т.д с остальными форматами файлов.